# No Guest Checkout with PayPal Adaptive Payment Digital Goods in Parallel mode

Tags: paypal, parallel-processing, payment

I just created a new PayPal classic app on developer.paypapl.com and made it work on the live site. Everything looks fine except for Guest Checkout. The app is approved conditionally.

I tried the checkout flow on various computers and browsers and even deleted cookies. Neither test worked.

Does anyone know if guest checkout is available with Adaptive Payment in Parallel mode when classic API is used?

Here is the page where PayPal Guest Checkout is missing
http://www.grabimo.com/bizGig.html?gigId=178125178667003

Comment: It should be fine.  Do you have PayPal Account Optional enabled in your PayPal account profile?

Comment: Yes, "PayPal Account Optional" is on my account. The parallel payment will have two receivers. I'm the app owner and one of the receiver. The other receiver might have no PayPal account at all.  Also, I think the optional on my account has nothing to do with the app.

Comment: Well if you're talking about receivers they will indeed need a PayPal account to receive their funds.

Comment: capulett I have tried your url and it seems I can pay without logging in. Did you solve your issue? I have a similar problem. Also, I can't find the "PayPal Account Optional" in my Paypal account profile. :\

Comment: From https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/products/ap-guest-payments/ Maybe your account is not "Premier or Business verified PayPal account"?